# Rocket League SDL_Init() Crash

Tags: nvidia, games, steam

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 and installed Steam + Rocket League. Rocket League at first was running without a problem but then after a few closes of the game it stopped opening. I attempted to run the game's launch script and received the following error

`SDL_Init() failed: No available video device`

I am using a nVidia GTX 970 with nVidia driver 390.42 installed.

**Update:** The issue was fixed by manually downloading SDL2 and then reinstalling SDL2 using the compiled source. [The thread that provided the solution for me](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=944671).

Comment: What is the output of `glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering"` ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I managed to fix the issue and updated the OP. I'll add my `glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering"` output for the sake of benefitting someone else:

`direct rendering: Yes`